Users opinion about moderator policy on added noise to questions/answers
As a moderator, I sometimes find myself in the position of having to evaluate whether to edit or not a question/answer for added noise which is useless from the information point of view.
I am referring in particular to those sentences which pertain to the users' abilities/when user asks for help/when suggestions are made. See for instance 
Uso della punteggiatura alla fine di affermazioni che hanno la medesima struttura sintattica delle domande
The user says he is not sure about the usage of a word and he gets a correction/suggestion from another user, learning he was right. 
In such cases, I would be tempted to delete the last part of the question (the PS) and the comments commenting on it, because it has nothing to do with the question itself.
The idea would be contributing to the overall quality of a post and eliminating all useless stuff. Of course, I am talking about resolved issues/finished discussions, not ongoing things.
On the other hand though, I feel like intruding people's things and I wouldn't want to be offensive.
This all starts to be relevant because of the growing number of users/questions/answers (which is great!). 
What does the community think about this?

Magari si potrebbero fare modifiche ma senza eliminare informazioni che, anche se inutili potrebbero indirettamente portare alla formulazione o alla soluzione di altri problemi.
Se delle informazioni non rilevanti sono molte, e se si vuole per forza fare una modifica sarebbe più logico concentrarle in una sezione separata dal resto della domanda, in modo da garantire una rapida e chiara comprensione della domanda, e dei dettagli in più in caso qualcuno fosse qui googlando quei termini...
